# Create Sharepoint Site via REST API with multiple owners

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, office365api, power-platform

So, I have a Power Automate Flow, which creates a Sharepoint Site using the Sharepoint REST API via "Send HTTP Request to Sharepoint" connector. I`ve following body:

```
{
  "request": {
    "Title": "@{variables('strSPName')}",
    "Url":"@{variables('strSPAddress')}",
    "Lcid": 1031,
    "ShareByEmailEnabled":true,
    "Description":"-",
    "WebTemplate":"SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
    "SiteDesignId":"-",
    "Owner":  "@{outputs('Get_my_profile_(V2)')?['body/mail']}"
  }
}
```

So right now I have only me as owner, but I need an additional owner.

I`ve tried to set two owners in an array like this:

```
"Owner":  ["@{outputs('Get_my_profile_(V2)')?['body/mail']}", "email@test.com"]
```

Unfortunately, I`m getting the following error:

```
An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is probably a cloud flow so please remove the power-automate-desktop tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can only set one owner when creating a site via the SPSiteManager endpoint. However, a workaround could be to add the second user to the Owners group directly after creation with a second POST request.

Below is an example
*The principal id of the sitegroup should be 3.*

Uri

```
_api/web/SiteGroups(3)/users
```

Body

```
{ 
 "__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" }, 
 "LoginName":"i:0#.f|membership|jane@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I also found this way to add an owner, but didn't understand the parameter for SiteGroups. I'll try, thanks!